# Replace in string with lodash

Tags: javascript, string, lodash

I have an object with several attributes that i want to replace in a string.

```
replaceBy:{
          "PRS_JOBS_MAQUINA":"PRS_JOBS_WORKCENTER",
          "CD_MAQ":"CD_WKC",
          "DT_INI_MAQ":"DT_INI_WKC",
          "DT_INI_JM" :"DT_INI_JW"
          }
```

Is there an eloquent way to do this with lodash?
Here is the string

```
" 

AND ( CD_JOB, DT_INI_JOB ) IN  (SELECT x.CD_JOB, x.DT_INI_JM FROM PRS_JOBS_MAQUINA x WHERE x.EMPRESA = ':EMPRESA' AND x.CD_MAQ = ':CD_MAQ' AND TO_CHAR(x.DT_INI_MAQ, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = ':DT_INI_MAQ'
AND TO_CHAR(x.DT_INI_JM, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '1900-01-01'  AND x.DT_FIM IS NULL )
```

"

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Why use a library? `for (var rb in replaceBy) str=  str.replace(new RegExp(rb, "g"),replaceBy[rb]);`

Comment: pure javascript: http://es6fiddle.net/itoeawvc/ (only replaces first occurence of each key)

Comment: @SimonHänisch - pretty much identical to, but less compatible than, my suggestion?

Comment: @mplungjan yeah somehow your comment wasn't loaded while I created the fiddle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
var yourString = 'your string';
_.forEach(replaceBy, function(value, key) {
    yourString = _.replace(string, key, value);
});
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it doesn't provide any context to explain how or why. Consider adding a sentence or two to explain your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.prototype.replace()` with a regexp that contain all search words, and replace them using `replace` callback:

```js
function replaceByMap(str, replaceBy) {
  var search = new RegExp(Object.keys(replaceBy).join('|'), 'g'); // creates a regexp of the strings to replace

  return str.replace(search, function(match) { // iterates the string, and replace the strings found with their replacements from the map
    return replaceBy[match];
  });
}

var replaceBy = {
  "PRS_JOBS_MAQUINA": "PRS_JOBS_WORKCENTER",
  "CD_MAQ": "CD_WKC",
  "DT_INI_MAQ": "DT_INI_WKC",
  "DT_INI_JM": "DT_INI_JW"
};

var str = "AND ( CD_JOB, DT_INI_JOB ) IN  (SELECT x.CD_JOB, x.DT_INI_JM FROM PRS_JOBS_MAQUINA x WHERE x.EMPRESA = ':EMPRESA' AND x.CD_MAQ = ':CD_MAQ' AND TO_CHAR(x.DT_INI_MAQ, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = ':DT_INI_MAQ' AND TO_CHAR(x.DT_INI_JM, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '1900-01-01'  AND x.DT_FIM IS NULL )";

var result = replaceByMap(str, replaceBy);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use a library?

```js
 var replaceBy={
              "PRS_JOBS_MAQUINA":"PRS_JOBS_WORKCENTER",
              "CD_MAQ":"CD_WKC",
              "DT_INI_MAQ":"DT_INI_WKC",
              "DT_INI_JM" :"DT_INI_JW"
              }, str=  "AND ( CD_JOB, DT_INI_JOB ) IN  (SELECT x.CD_JOB, x.DT_INI_JM FROM PRS_JOBS_MAQUINA x WHERE x.EMPRESA = ':EMPRESA' AND x.CD_MAQ = ':CD_MAQ' AND TO_CHAR(x.DT_INI_MAQ, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = ':DT_INI_MAQ' AND TO_CHAR(x.DT_INI_JM, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '1900-01-01'  AND x.DT_FIM IS NULL )"

for (var rb in replaceBy) {
  str = str.replace(new RegExp(rb, "g"),replaceBy[rb]);
}
console.log(str)
```